# Finite groups as intersection of algebraic groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Well known that any finite number of points can be seen as intersection of two algebraic curves. Is it true that any finite group $G$ can be seen as intersection of two (connected) one dimensional algebraic subgroups $G_1, G_2$ of two dimensional algebraic group $G^*$? Also is it true that if $G$ is abelian?

In this questions groups $G_1, G_2, G^*$ are over field $\mathbb{C}$. I found this question after study of complex representation theory of finite groups, and i want to understand what is geometric nature of characters $G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: As stated, yes, for stupid reasons. Take  for a 2-dimensional group the product of G with  (Ga)^2, and the two subgroups G times Ga times {0} and G times {0} times Ga. As probably wanted, no, for the more interesting reason that a connected one-dimensional algebraic group is commutative.

Comment: 1) Yes, let $D$ be any 1-dimensional algebraic group with unit 1. Then $G$ can be viewed as the intersection of $G\times D\times\{1\}$ and $G\times\{1\}\times D$ in $G\times D\times D$. 2) In case you forgot to assume that the big group $G^*$ is connected, the answer is no just because a finite subgroup of a 2-dimensional connected complex algebraic group has to be abelian, and even it cannot be any abelian finite group.